# Match internal ending set of characters in string using regular expression

Tags: regex

On the following two strings I'd like to create a regular expression that returns the binding property and value for the visibility binding.

In this string I would want to get back: visible:visible()

```
"attr:{fill:fill(),stroke:stroke()},visible:visible()"
```

In this string I would want to get back: visible:propertyIsVisible()

```
"attr:{fill:fill(),stroke:stroke()},visible:propertyIsVisible(),click:clickEvent"
```

In this string I would want to get back: visible:properties.visibilityProperty

```
"visible:properties.visibilityProperty, click:clickMe"
```

Any regexperts out there have a good suggestion for getting this using a regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
(visible:[A-z\(\)\.-_]*)
```